# Laravel logic for implementing models with different methods

Tags: php, interface, model, laravel-5

First post ever : ) I am learning Laravel 5 and want to do something "the right way".

I want to manage all my home automation systems with php/Laravel i.e. lightning.

I have many types of lightning control i.e. X10, Philips Hue and Belkin WeMo. Each type has different ways to put light ON/OFF/brightness/etc.

I currently have a "Light" model with `"type" = hue||wemo||x10`, but I don't want to do:

```
class Light extends Model
{
    function off()
    {
        switch $this->type
        {
            case'x10': x10_close_light($this->address); break;
            case'hue': hue_close_light($this->address); break;
            case'wemo': wemo_close_light($this->address); break;
        }
    }
}
```

I would prefer to have an Interface like:

```
interface LightInterface
{
    function close();
    function open();
    function dim($value);
    function get_status();
    etc...
}
```

Then, have different classes and/or methods for each type of lightning.

I read about eloquent's relations (one-to-one, polymorphism and other) but I am not seeing the big picture here.

What is the right way to do this in Laravel 5/Eloquent?

Comment: how you are managing this light on or off in database I mean do you have any field in database which values like 1 for on or 0 for off etc?

Comment: I do have a boolean `is_on` field in database for all lights, and this value is updated each time a manual open/close action is triggered. I also have a cron job updating this value for wemo and hue lights as they can return a status on demand, but not the x10. Everything is controlled with command line and each type of light have different commands, what I need is a way to simply call $Light->open() from my LightsController on any type of light, and have the appropriate command fired (without using 'switch' or 'what if' on `type`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit more digging into Laravel and I'm adding another [and final] answer here because the answer to my initial question is : **Polymorphic Relations** !

Now I see the big picture. Thanks Internet.

e.g.

```
class Light extends Model
{
    function control()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    function toggle()
    {       
        $inverse = ! $this->control->actual_state;
        $this->control->state($inverse);
    }

    function off()
    {
        $this->control->state(false);
    }

    ...
}
```

then,

```
class Light_x10 extends Model
{
    public function state($state)
    {
        //... x10 specific coding (I use Mochad)
    }
}

class Light_hue extends Model
{
    public function state($state)
    {
       // ... Phillips Hue specific coding (I use hue-cli)
       // $cmd = $state===false? 'off' : 'on'
       // exec("hue light {$this->address} $cmd");
    }
}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Check on dependency injection concepts in laravel. That might help you.
[Like this](http://www.sitepoint.com/dependency-injection-laravels-ioc/)

Comment: I'll read this... looks promising. Thanks. Will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution I've found for my project is very simple:

```
class Light extends Model
{
    function control()
    {
        switch($this->type)
        {
            case'hue': return $this->belongsTo('App\Light_hue', 'control_id');

            case'wemo': return $this->belongsTo('App\Light_wemo', 'control_id');

            case'x10': return $this->belongsTo('App\Light_x10', 'control_id');
        }
    }

    function toggle()
    {       
        $this->control->toggle();
    }

    function off()
    {
        $this->control->toggle(0);
    }

    ...
}
```

I only need to have 'one switch block' to define which model to use for each type of light. `control_id` is used for the databse relations between Light Model and Light_`type` Models i.e. Light_x10, Light_hue, etc.

All Light_`type` models are implementing the same interface, and all have different code for switching on/off, dimming, etc.

**EDIT:** Eager loading doesn't work with this "solution"... I'm still looking for a real answer

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work well with eager loading : (